# Phoenix - issues managing migration mix tasks for multiple databases

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I've set up my Phoenix app so that it connects to two databases. I'm having a little trouble managing my migrations and the various Ecto `mix` tasks - specifically, creating new migrations and rolling back migrations.

First off, here's the repo configuration from `config/dev.exs`

```
config :phoenix_backend, PhoenixBackend.Repo,
    adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
    username: "postgres",
    password: "postgres",
    database: "phoenix_backend_dev",
    hostname: "localhost",
    pool_size: 10

config :phoenix_backend, PhoenixBackend.SearchRepo,
   adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
   username: "postgres",
   password: "postgres",
   database: "phoenix_backend_search_dev",
   hostname: "localhost",
   pool_size: 10
```

Initially, my app just had one repo, the default `Repo`, I added `SearchRepo` later on.

When I first set up `SearchRepo`, I ran `$ mix gen.model` to create a new model in that database.  The migration went into `priv/repo/migrations`, and then I adjusted the auto-generated module definition to point at my new database - I changed

```
defmodule PhoenixBackend.Repo.Migrations.CreateUserRole do
```

to

```
defmodule PhoenixBackend.SearchRepo.Migrations.CreateSearch do
```

When I ran `$ mix ecto.migrate`, I got the error

```
Could not find migrations directory "priv/search_repo/migrations" for repo PhoenixBackend.SearchRepo.
```

So I created that directory, moved the migration into it, and ran the migration again - perfect it worked!

So this brings me to the problem(s)...

I now have two migration directories in `priv` - `priv/repo/migrations` and `priv/search_repo/migrations`.

1. If I run `$ mix ecto.migrate new_migration`, this will create a migration file for `new_migration` in **both** directories.
2. If I run `$ mix ecto.rollback`, this **only** rolls back migrations from `priv/repo/migrations`.
3. If I run `$ mix ecto.migrate`, this runs the migrations from **both** directories.

So what I'd like to know is, how can I standardize this behavior? Is the problem with the commands that I'm running, or is there something in the configuration of the app that I need to change to point at these different directories?

I would love to be able to create migrations and point them to the specific directories, and I'd love to be able to specify which databases migrate and rollback point to.  How can I customize this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option you are looking for is `-r CustomRepo`

```
$ mix ecto.gen.migration add_something -r MyApp.SearchRepo
$ mix ecto.migrate -r MyApp.SearchRepo
```

Its all in the mix help. To get that

```
$ mix help ecto.gen.migration
$ mix help ecto.migrate
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the acknowledgement. Don't forget to mark it as answered :)